# Enforce compile-time constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

In C++11 we get `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int foo (int x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

Is it possible to make invocations of `foo` with a dynamic value of `x` a compile time error? That is, I want to create a `foo` such that one can only pass in `constexpr` arguments.

Comment: You can always turn it into a function template: `template<int x> int foo() { return x + 1; }`

Comment: Note that `constexpr` was partially called into being to counteract all the syntactical workarounds you are going to see in the answers here.

Comment: `#define foo(N) foo<N>()` looks viable to me.

Comment: Alternatively, in non-evaluated contexts, `#define REQUIRE_CEXPR(E) []{ constexpr auto x = E; return x; }()` and you can say `foo(REQUIRE_CEXPR(1 + 2))` (C++14). For C++11, you can do `[]()->typename std::decay<decltype((E))>::type` to explicitly specify the type. Uglier though :)

Comment: Non-answer: store the result in a `constexpr`.

Answer (score 9):

Replace it with a metafunction:

```
template <int x> struct foo { static constexpr int value = x + 1; };
```

Usage:

```
foo<12>::value
```

Comment: Or better, give it an `operator()` so that is resembles a function call.

Comment: @rubenvb: Even better, use a variable template: `template <int N> int bar = foo<N>::value;`. Usage: `bar<12>`. Available in C++14.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way guarantee that a `constexpr` function, even the most trivial one, will be evaluated by the compiler unless absolutely necessary. That is, unless it appears in a place where its value is required at compile time, e.g. in a template. In order to enforce the compiler to do the evaluation during compilation, you can do the following:

```
constexpr int foo_implementation (int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

#define foo(x) std::integral_constant<int, foo_implementation(x)>::value
```

and then use `foo` in your code as usual

```
int f = foo(123);
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it guarantees compile-time evaluation, and you'll get a compilation error if you pass a run-time variable to `foo`:

```
int a = 2;
int f = foo(a); /* Error: invalid template argument for 'std::integral_constant',
                   expected compile-time constant expression */
```

The not so nice thing is that it requires a macro, but this seems currently inevitable if you want both guaranteed compile-time evaluation and pretty code. (I'd love to be proven wrong though!)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can now be done in purely idiomatic C++, since C++20 added support for this kind of problem. You annotate a function with `consteval` and can be sure that it's being evaluated during compile time. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval

```
consteval int foo( int x ) {
    return x + 1;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    return foo( argc ); // This will not compile
    return foo( 1 );    // This works
}
```

Also see [this godbolt.org demo](https://godbolt.org/z/839h76n81) in the 3 most relevant compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `static_assert` as shown in this example

```
#include<iostream>

constexpr int foo(int x) {
        return x+1;
}

int main() {
        // Works since its static
        std::cout << foo(2) << std::endl;
        static_assert(foo(2) || foo(2) == 0, "Not Static");

        // Throws an compile error
        int in = 3;
        std::cout << foo(in) << std::endl;
        static_assert(foo(in) || foo(in) == 0, "Not Static");
}
```

For more infos: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: I don't have a compiler ATM with `constexpr`, but wouldn't this idea extend to putting the `static_assert` directly into `foo`? E.g. `constexpr int foo(int x) { static_assert(x == x, "Not Static"); return x+1; }`

Comment: @ThomasEding. You could but then you would loose the flexibility of using the same function as run-time-evaluated function. Since `static_assert` checked at compile time it will also not affect runtime.